# Implement an array of stacks in C

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

Implement an array of stacks where stacks are defined :

```
typedef struct StackNode {

   int data;

   StackNode* next;

} StackNode;
```

Each array element points to a stack, each stack is initialized as an empty stack.
When you start adding elements it will start adding them to the stack in `Stacks[0];`
if you say `-2` in stdin and then `4` for example, the next entries will go to `Stacks[4];`

For example:

```
5 10 -2 3 9 7 89 -1
will result in :
Stacks[0] -> 10 -> 5
Stacks[1]
Stacks[2]
Stacks[3] -> 89 -> 7 -> 9
```

`-1` will stop the code from running.

I am having problem with implementing an array of stacks so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It is not homework, but it is part of the code i am writing and i am trying to finish it as soon as possible. I think I understand everything but the idea of implementing the array. So if this way just a stack to push and pop elements it would've been easy. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Can you post the code that is actually operating on the structure? Or are you having problems even getting started? I think this probably needs the homework tag, as jinguy suggested.

Comment: even if it is not a homework?

Comment: @c2009l123: Sorry, I had posted that comment as you were writing your reply indicating that to Rom, so I didn't see it until after my comment was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int t = 0, index = 0;
while(t != -1)
{
  scanf("%d", &t);
  if(t == -2)
  {
    scanf("%d", &t);
    index = t;
    continue;
  }
  if(t >= 0)
    push(stacks[index], t);
}
```

Comment: and push function would just be like
push(StackNode *tp, int t) right? i mean not StackNode *tp[int i] or something like that?

Comment: If `stacks` is an array of pointers to StackNode objects, yeah, your signature for push function is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In line 3 of

```
typedef struct StackNode {
   int data;
   StackNode* next;          /* line 3 */
} StackNode;
```

the type `StackNode` does not yet exist. The type `StackNode` only begins to exist once the type `struct StackNode` is fully parsed.

But the type `struct StackNode` already exists at that point. It is still incomplete, but you can declare pointers to it.

```
typedef struct StackNode {
   int data;
   struct StackNode* next;          /* line 3 */
} StackNode;
```

Comment: This is not what i am facing a problem with though. For example you can : StackNode *Stacks[10]; to create an array of stacks of size 10. However i am having problem to do operations like pushing for example to a specific number in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like the following (tested):

```
//includes
#define SIZE 10


typedef struct StackNode{
 int data ;
 struct StackNode* next ;
}StackNode ;



StackNode* new_stackNode(int num)
{
 StackNode* ptr = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode)) ;
 ptr->data = num ;
 ptr->next = 0 ;
 return ptr ;
}



int main()
{
 StackNode *arr[SIZE] = {0};
 int st_index = 0 ;
 int num = 0 ;
 while(num != -1)
 {
  scanf("%d",&num);
  if( num == -2 )
  st_index++ ;
  else
  {
   StackNode* ptr = new_stackNode(num) ;
   ptr->next = arr[st_index] ;
   arr[st_index] = ptr ;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a stack, it looks like a linked list. Of course you can implement stack-like semantics using a linked list, but it's generally not what is meant by "a stack".

To push a new number, you would need to:

- Allocate a new `StackNode`.
- Initialize it with the new number.
- Link it to the previous.

You could encapsulate this into a function:

```
void stack_push(StackNode *root, int value)
{
    /* Code omitted */
}
```

Then you'd just need to provide the proper stack in order to control onto which of your many stacks to push the new number:

```
stack_push(&Stacks[2], 4711);
```

Comment: I have done that, but how to push the number to a specific stack that is linked to a specific number in the array. For example i want to push number (3) to Stacks[5] or pop a number from Stacks[2]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the bottom of [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), you'll see an example of what I *think* you are trying to implement. What you have is a linked list. Additionally, here are some handy [doubly linked list helpers](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/list.html) which might serve as example.

If you post the actual usage of your code as-is, you might receive a better (more specific) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must first get an array of `StackNode`s:

```
StackNode ** stacks = malloc(sizeof(StackNode*) * 5); /* allocate 5 stack nodes */
stacks[0] = malloc(sizeof(StackNode)); /* allocate first stack */
...
```

Now you have a function `push(StackNode *, int value)`. To push on a certain stack, call it with `push(stacks[2], value)` (to push on the third stack, for example).

Comment: do i need to do that one by one? what if i have 100 stacks, would i just loop over them? That seems kind of inefficient